# Create two JpaRepository for same entity, one for internal use, the other for rest operations

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I would like to create an entity that is exposed with spring data rest and secured. Example :

```
@PreAuthorize("denyAll")
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "exposed-users")
public UserJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, User> {
    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    Page<User> findOne(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

This is maybe a bit silly (but just for the example and a bit more complicated in my case) : only the `/exposed-users/{id}` should be read accessible (via GET), and everything else should be denied.

The problem is that this makes the repository unusable for the rest of the application, for example a userJpaRepository.count() will fail because of the `@PreAuthorize("denyAll")`.

So I thought why not create two JpaRepositories for the same entity :

- the one above, for external REST access, secured
- another one for all internal uses, not secured, with no rest annotation, like this :

```
public InternalUserJpaRepository extends JpaRepository {
}
```

I can't get this to work though ... more precisely it works randomly, sometimes the Users are exposed with no security on the default `/users` mapping (so the `InternalUserJpaRepository` is used), sometimes the Users are exposed correctly on the `/exposed-users` mapping, with proper security.

I'd like to remove the random factor :-)

Is there a way to properly do this ?

I already thought of ditching the method security altogether and go with a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (with ant patterns et al) but if I would prefer staying with method security if possible.